# Google analytics and UTM parameters

Tags: google-analytics

I'm new to google analytics and UTM parameters and have, what I believe to be, a fairly simple question.

I have read about and understand what UTM parameters are and how GA uses them, but is there anything I need to do to my site, other than include the generic GA javascript in the default layout page?  Do I need to parse the parameters from the query strings and pass them somewhere or does GA just handle it?

Comment: As long as you have the campaign source, medium and name, Google Analytics will do all the parsing for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don`t need to do something special - just put correct GATC on your site pages and mark links, which you placed outside your site by UTM URL builder. GA parses all for You.